# Setting a rule for an incoming mail (read or unread)

Tags: email, microsoft-outlook, script, microsoft-outlook-2010, vba

I need a little advice on Outlook 2010.

There is this situation:
- one webmail account which is used by a several people (using web browser or phone to access it)
- one computer with MS Outlook 2010 client connected to this webmail (via IMAP)

My question is:
- is it possible to set such a rule which would always copy any incoming e-mail to a given folder?

The current issue:
- it is possible to set a rule which copies incoming e-mail to a given folder but that e-mail has to be marked as 'unread' ... if this e-mail was already read by someone else on a different device, using webmail access via a phone, for example; after opening Outlook, this mail will not be copied to that given folder.

Any idea how to solve this issue, please?

Answer (score 0):

Following VBA Code will move copy of the incoming Email and mark it UnRead

Create Rule and Apply on messages I receive -> Next -> Next -> Run Script

```
Option Explicit
Public Sub MoveItems(olItem As Outlook.MailItem)
    Dim olApp As New Outlook.Application
    Dim olNameSpace As Outlook.NameSpace
    Dim olInbox As Outlook.MAPIFolder
    Dim olDestFolder As Outlook.MAPIFolder
    Dim olItems As Outlook.Items
    Dim CopyItem As Object

    Set olNameSpace = olApp.GetNamespace("MAPI")
    Set olInbox = olNameSpace.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderInbox)
    Set olItems = olInbox.Items

    '// loop
    While TypeName(olItem) <> "Nothing"
        Set olDestFolder = olInbox.Folders("TEMP") '// Folder Name
        Set CopyItem = olItem.Copy
        olItem.Move olDestFolder
        olItem.UnRead = True '// <- Mark UnRead
        Set olItem = olItems.FindNext
    Wend
    '// Clean up
    Set olNameSpace = Nothing
    Set olInbox = Nothing
    Set olDestFolder = Nothing
    Set olItems = Nothing
    Set olItem = Nothing
    Set CopyItem = Nothing
End Sub
```